# Crystal Report changes the spelling while exporting to PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am facing a strange issue in the latest version of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. While exporting the report to PDF, it is changing the spelling of the words

For e.g.

In Database : पोसनलाल बाराबुध्द्दे जी, दुर्ग

Crystal Reports PDF : पपसनललल बलरलबबधधदधदद जज, दबरधग

I am using Arial Unicode MS font. Also, it was working fine in the previous version.

Comment: Which font you are using Calibri?

Comment: Nope. Arial Unicode MS TrueType

Comment: Can you play around with changing the font? or if you are getting the correct names from database?

Comment: Done that too. Same results.

Comment: discuss in chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177577/crystal-report-discussions

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming the latest version of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP 23.

I downgraded from the latest SP 23 to SP 22, and it's working fine now

[image: What it should be. Which is coming in SP 22]

[image: What is coming]

The first image is SP23, and second image is SP22

I guess there is some difference in interpretation of UTF characters in the latest release.

Comment: I am having Unicode related issue in Crystal Report Viewer in Visual Studio (VS 2017 and CRVS 23). Whenever I open any xyz.rpt file which uses unicode using Crystal Report Viewer inside Visual Studio the text changes.